# How do I build and install gala plugins on freya?

Tags: gala, development

There's loads of cool in development plugins like tiling and chat bubbles, how do I get them running? as a followup question is there an easy way to begin developing plugins for gala?

I don't mind complicated answers I'm already fairly well versed in shell commands and compiling.

Comment: I am curious about this too actually, nice question ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to give a look at the active branches at the [Gala launchpad page](https://code.launchpad.net/gala).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [gala/plugins/template/README](https://github.com/elementary/gala/blob/8e142b9ef967d857c4cf311eaa986b4768432169/plugins/template/README) will help you out. Unfortunately I can't currently give you a better answer than that because I'm trying myself to figure out what the content of that file actually means.

I remember reading a text about how Gala loads plugins, but can't find it at the moment.

So far I have understood that for the plugin to compile its directory needs to be added to the build.meson file (`subdir('plugins/<plugin directory>')`).